# why it does not calculate as per the formula in the table?

Tags: php, mysql

I am entering 3 values from the user. And I want to calculate the as per the formula which is in the table column. I get the formula printed, but I want the calculation to happen according to the formula. I am using php and mysql.
Please help me and guide me how to achieve it this way?

Html code:

```
<form action="testcalc1.php" method="post">
Size 1: <input type="text" name="size1" /><br><br>
Size 2: <input type="text" name="size2" /><br><br>
Quantity: <input type="text" name="quanity" /><br><br>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Php Code:

```
$s1 = $_POST['size1'];
    $s2 = $_POST['size2'];
    $s3 = $_POST['size2'];

    $rec= mysql_query("SELECT unit_cost FROM mat WHERE mat_name='ball'") or die(mysql_error());

    $s5 = mysql_fetch_assoc($rec);
    $s4 = $s5['unit_cost'];

    echo $s4;
```

Mat table:

**mat_name || unit_cost**

ball || $s1*$s2*$s3

Output what I am getting it now is :: $s1*$s2*$s3

Comment: how do you insert the record into the table? can you show that part also?

Comment: You would need to evaluate your `$s4` expression: http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php. But I would definitely not do that with un-sanitized user input.

Comment: Right now i directly inserted the record through mysql phpmyadmin page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
eval('$s4='.$s5['unit_cost'].';');
```

or

```
$s4=eval('return '.$s5['unit_cost'].';');
```

However, you should not use `mysql_*` functions (use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`) and it's not safe to use `$_POST` variables in `eval()` if you do not check them if they really are numbers.

Comment: I tried what you did suggeste me to do, but I got an error



Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in C:\wamp\www\test\testcalc1.php(24) : eval()'d code on line 1



and what you suggested me is the line number 24.

Comment: Sorry... see edited version - a semicolon at the end should be ok.

Comment: I tried the edited version, there was no error but there was nothing printed on the page.

Comment: I edited it, now should be ok. BTW, you could've checked in the PHP manual and correct it yourself.

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much for your help and efforts. I am a newbie to Php so I am not very familier with it. Thank you once again.

Comment: As a hint I suggest to look at php.net manual. It's quite well written.